# Stripe how to set prefered language when using 2 payment methods

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I successfully integrated the Stripe checkout in my Java web application.

The payment method has been 'card' so far. I'd like to add the method 'sofort' which can be done adding this line`paymentMethodTypes.add("sofort")`.

```
    Stripe.apiKey = retrieveKey("CLIENT_SECRET_KEY");

    ArrayList<String> paymentMethodTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    paymentMethodTypes.add("card");
    params.put("payment_method_types", paymentMethodTypes);        

    ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> lineItems = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, Object> lineItem = new HashMap<>();
    lineItem.put("name", title);
    lineItem.put("images", images);

    lineItem.put("amount", price);
    lineItem.put("currency", "eur");
    lineItem.put("quantity", 1);
    lineItems.add(lineItem);
    params.put("line_items", lineItems);
    params.put("customer_email", email);

    params.put("success_url", DOMAIN_URL);
    params.put("cancel_url", DOMAIN_URL + "/cancel.xhtml");

    RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.builder().setStripeAccount(CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID).build();

    session = Session.create(params, requestOptions);
```

Now how can I set my prefered language?
I tried adding this lines to my code; without success.

```
PaymentIntentCreateParams.PaymentMethodOptions mtdh = PaymentIntentCreateParams.PaymentMethodOptions.builder().putExtraParam("sofort[preferred_language]", "de").build(); 
params.put("Payment_method_options", mtdh);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe Checkout Sessions do not support setting a preferred language for Sofort specifically (see [the accepted properties for `payment_method_options` in Stripe's documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_method_options)), but you can [set the `locale` for the entire Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-locale).

Here's how you would do so in your existing code:

```
params.put("locale", "de");
```